# Magento 2: Display "Call For Price" instead of $0 or $0.00

Tags: magento2

I have searched and found several options for Magento 1 but the only option so far for Magento 2 is an extension and it displays Free instead of Call for Price.

I have seen a couple of options that may be for Magento 2 but no idea which files they are editing.

Does anyone know which file & location of said file to edit and with what?

Additionally, since there is no price I would prefer to disable the add to cart button for these items if this is possible.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is better if you engage a developer.

Answer (score 2):

To display Price on Request on the Category / Product pages you could create final_price.phtml in your custom Theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */

$productId = $block->getSaleableItem()->getId();

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $priceModel */
$priceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('final_price');
$idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
$schema = ($block->getZone() == 'item_view') ? true : false;

?>
<?php if ($block->getSaleableItem()->getFinalPrice() == 0): ?>
    <span class="price-on-request">
        <?php echo __('Price on Request'); ?>
    <span>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if ($block->getPriceType('custom_price')->getCustomAmount() < $block->getPriceType('custom_price')->getCustomAmount(null,null,['regular_price'=>True,'price_type'=>'custom_price'])): ?>
        <span class="special-price">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($block->getPriceType('custom_price')->getCustomAmount(), [
                'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
                'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('custom-special-price-' . $idSuffix),
                'price_type'        => 'custom_price',
                'include_container' => true,
                'schema' => $schema
            ]); ?>
        </span>
        <span class="old-price">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($block->getPriceType('custom_price')->getCustomAmount(null,null,['regular_price'=>True,'price_type'=>'custom_price_regular']), [
                'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
                'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('custom-price-' . $idSuffix),
                'price_type'        => 'custom_price',
                'include_container' => true,
                'skip_adjustments'  => true
            ]); ?>
        </span>
    <?php elseif ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
        <span class="special-price">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
                'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
                'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
                'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
                'include_container' => true,
                'schema' => $schema
            ]); ?>
        </span>
        <span class="old-price">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
                'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
                'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
                'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
                'include_container' => true,
                'skip_adjustments'  => true
            ]); ?>
        </span>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($block->getPriceType('final_price')->getCustomAmount(null,null,['price_type'=>'final_price']), [
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($block->showMinimalPrice()): ?>
        <?php if ($block->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()):?>
            <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl(); ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmountMinimal(); ?>
            </a>
        <?php else:?>
            <span class="minimal-price-link">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmountMinimal(); ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And for the shopping cart you can create a Plugin on

> Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer $subject
 * @param $result
 * @return string
 */
public function afterGetUnitPriceHtml(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer $subject,
    $result
) {
    if ($subject->getProduct()->getFinalPrice() > 0) {
        return $result;
    }
    return __('Price on Request');
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer $subject
 * @param $result
 * @return string
 */
public function afterGetRowTotalHtml(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer $subject,
    $result
) {
    if ($subject->getProduct()->getFinalPrice() > 0) {
        return $result;
    }
    return __('Price on Request');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!  After creating the first file things went a bit crazy, if is possible there is anything missing?  I was unable to view any individual product pages, and the home page only showed a few parts all of the rest of my graphics were gone.

Comment: After applying this code make sure there is no issue in version upgrade.  @Mr. Lewis Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change code in file : Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions

`public function getFormatedPrice()
    {
        return '';`

```
}
```

also, you can use

http://www.mlx-store.com/magento2-extensions/catalog/hide-price-call-for-price-for-magento-2.html